# How to monitor the response time of page level individual elements of web page using RPT?

Tags: performance, load-testing, rpt

I want to measure the response time of the page level elements of a web page during load testing using IBM  [Rational Performance Tester](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/performance).

For example, suppose I have clicked a submit button after filling a form on a web page. I want to measure the response time of this transaction ( i.e. clicking on submitting button and getting its response back). In a simple sense, I want to track response time for individual elements of a web page to know which part is taking more time to respond.

How can I do this using RPT?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all page element response time under the "Page Element Performance Report". I am using RPT v 10 where we have that option, check with your RPT version this is avilable or not.